# Android: how to filter logcat trace files?

Tags: android, logging

I got a logcat file from another user which has troubles with the app. The file is pretty big and contains a lot of verbose logging information.
Is there a tool to filter for TAGs or App? Maybe is there some way to use LogCat itself for that?

Comment: You could just use grep and redirect the output to another file.

Answer (score 1):

At least in my version, I see filter tools on the left. There's a big green plus which will add a new filter, which you can filter on a number of items, including the TAG.

Answer (score 0):

As cyph3r wrote: Just use some command line tools such as grep

```
cat mylog.txt | grep "myTag"
```